# What mean to use in odometer calculation based on model?

Tags: mean, types-of-averages

Im trying to figure out what would be considered a valid calculation.

Imagine I have a dataset that looks like that:

```
+------+-------+----------+-------+
| make | model | odometer | year |
+------+-------+----------+-------+
| audi | a4    |    77000 |  2012 |
| audi | a4    |    94093 |  2012 |
| audi | a4    |   129873 |  2012 |
| audi | a4    |   125000 |  2012 |
+------+-------+----------+-------+
```

What I want to calculate is the average number of kilometers that car with above set of parameters (make,model,year) traveled a day.

I've started with the following where `d` is the number of days between the odometer value was taken and the day when the car was made (xxx-01-01).  `km_d` is the `odometer/d`:

```
+------+---------+----------+
| d    | km_d    | odometer |
+------+---------+----------+
| 6523 | 38.0402 |   250000 |
| 6523 | 39.5068 |   259639 |
| 6523 | 31.8016 |   209000 |
| 6523 | 27.3889 |   180000 |
+------+---------+----------+
```

I've read about different mean calculations but wasn't sure which one would need to be applied in my situation.